# ImageButtons not arranging correctly

Tags: java, android

I've set my buttons to be arranged from top to bottom in order of Facebook, Instagram, Twitter and Reddit but it's not doing that, it's only showing Facebook and Reddit and I don't know why.
I've got my buttons to automatically resize on Activity creation with this code:

```
    public void getScreenRes() {
    DisplayMetrics display = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int screenwidth = display.widthPixels;
    int screenheight = display.heightPixels;
    double buttonheight = screenwidth / 2.66666667;
    int buttonheightint= (int) Math.round(buttonheight);
    ImageButton fbLogin = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.facebookLogin);
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams fb = fbLogin.getLayoutParams();
    fb.width = screenwidth;
    fb.height = buttonheightint;
    fbLogin.setLayoutParams(fb);
    ImageButton instaLogin = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.instagramLogin);
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams insta = instaLogin.getLayoutParams();
    insta.width = screenwidth;
    insta.height = buttonheightint;
    instaLogin.setLayoutParams(insta);
    ImageButton twitLogin = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.twitterLogin);
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams twit = instaLogin.getLayoutParams();
    twit.width = screenwidth;
    twit.height = buttonheightint;
    twitLogin.setLayoutParams(twit);
    ImageButton redditLogin = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.redditLogin);
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams reddit = instaLogin.getLayoutParams();
    reddit.width = screenwidth;
    reddit.height = buttonheightint;
    redditLogin.setLayoutParams(reddit);
}
```

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:paddingTop="16dp"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.eren.valour.FirstTimeLogin">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="@string/getStarted"
    android:id="@+id/getStartedText"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
   />
   <ImageButton
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
       android:background="@drawable/facebook"
       android:id="@+id/facebookLogin"
       android:onClick="facebookLogin"

       />
   <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/instagram"
        android:layout_below="@+id/facebookLogin"
        android:id="@+id/instagramLogin"
        android:onClick="instagramLogin"
        />
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/twitter"
        android:layout_below="@+id/instagramLogin"
        android:id="@+id/twitterLogin"
        android:onClick="twitterLogin"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/reddit"
        android:layout_below="@+id/twitterLogin"
        android:id="@+id/redditLogin"
        android:onClick="redditLogin"
        />
```

What it looks like now:
[image]

Comment: There must be something wrong with your resources, some of them may be corrupted, btw since you layout is very simple i would rather use a `LinearLayout`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the corresponding Layoutparams.

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams reddit = instaLogin.getLayoutParams();
```

should be

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams reddit = redditLogin.getLayoutParams();
```

the same with the Twitter Login:

```
 ViewGroup.LayoutParams twit = twitLogin.getLayoutParams();
```

What youre doing is taking the instagram layoutparams and applying it to 3 buttons so they all get placed on top of another, so only the last shows. Probably just a copy+past error on your side, but that should fix it.

If that does not fix it, the problem should be in the layout file. Try using a LinearLayout or setting the correct attributes for your RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your Layout from `RelativLayout` to `LinearLayout`. That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can put it into a LinearLayout with a weightsum Like so. Without the java method.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical"
          android:paddingTop="16dp" android:weightSum="5"
          tools:context="com.eren.valour.FirstTimeLogin">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/getStartedText" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_weight="1" android:padding="50dp" // you can tweak this figure here
    android:text="getStarted\nhere" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/facebookLogin" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/fb" android:onClick="facebookLogin"/>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/instagramLogin" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/insta" android:onClick="instagramLogin"/>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/twitterLogin" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/twit" android:onClick="twitterLogin"/>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/redditLogin" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/reddit" android:onClick="redditLogin"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: view]

Answer (score 0):

Update your XMl..
Instead of RelativeLayout ,I Think you should you should use LinearLayout and Weight propert like this ...

```
      <LineaLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.eren.valour.FirstTimeLogin"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/getStarted"
        android:id="@+id/getStartedText"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_weight="1"
       />
       <ImageButton
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
           android:background="@drawable/facebook"
           android:id="@+id/facebookLogin"
           android:onClick="facebookLogin"
    android:layout_weight="1"

           />
       <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/instagram"
            android:layout_below="@+id/facebookLogin"
            android:id="@+id/instagramLogin"
            android:onClick="instagramLogin"
    android:layout_weight="1"
            />
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/twitter"
            android:layout_below="@+id/instagramLogin"
            android:id="@+id/twitterLogin"
            android:onClick="twitterLogin"
    android:layout_weight="1"
            />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/reddit"
            android:layout_below="@+id/twitterLogin"
            android:id="@+id/redditLogin"
            android:onClick="redditLogin"
android:layout_weight="1"
            />
```

Also you don't need this method `getScreenRes()` anymore.